# Ruby. How can I copy and paste in irb on Windows?

Tags: windows, ruby, console, copy-paste, irb

How can I copy and paste in irb (Interactive Ruby Shell) on Windows?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To avoid having to open the drop-down menu and clicking, you need to change the command window settings.  To do this, right-click the title bar, choose Properties, turn on "QuickEdit Mode" under the Properties tab (and keep "Insert Mode" on), then OK.

Now, to copy: drag to select, right-click to copy.

To paste: right-click with no selection.

Answer (score 5):

To copy: Hit alt-space, choose Edit, choose Mark, drag-select the text, hit enter.

To paste: Hit alt-space, choose Edit, choose Paste.

Answer (score 2):

For CLI copy/paste:

Copy : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd>
Paste : <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. The 'Shift+Insert' works for pasting. Not sure about the 'Ctrl+Insert' for copying though.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), a replacement for Windows' terrible command-line chrome. It offers fully redefinable keyboard shortcuts plus tabs, so it's ideal for IRB.

Answer (score 0):

check out console2--very nice and allows you to paste by using right click or what not.

Update: conemu is even better: http://conemu.github.io/